# Can I ask a question about important story arcs?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I really want to start reading about [New Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Genesis) and [Apokolips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apokolips).

Can I ask a question about what graphic novel(s) and/or story arcs I should read to get started?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_World_(comics)

Comment: You're good people @Richard :)

Comment: No.  You're welcome to ask questions about insignificant story arcs, but important ones are off limits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading/Viewing order questions are allowed on this site, as long as you have clear and somewhat objective criteria for the installments and/or order thereof you want us to provide. So do not ask things like "What are the good story arcs?", but a question about which ones have crucial backstory or are amenable to new readers should be perfectly answerable (unless the series is extremely long, in which case you'd need to narrow it down a bit more).

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot.